# Easily setting numerical values for geometry, like Lightwave's Modeler does

Tags: mesh, interface, edit-mode

I'm moving from Lightwave to Blender, and there's something that's super easy in Modeler that I can't work out how to do in Blender.

In Modeler if I have geometry selected and hit <kbd>i</kbd> I get the info panel which gives me position and other info on any / all of the selected geometry.

[image]

This is particularly useful if I want to set a bunch of verts to a particular position, on any or all of the axes—I can just type in a position (or weight value) and apply it to all selected vertices. Is there any way of seeing or editing vertex info directly  in Blender?

[image]

Even without the info panel it's a one-step operation to assign a value to any selected geometry, I hit v and get a set value dialog. This works for verts, edges and faces. Does this exist for Blender?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the N Item menu? In edit mode it lets you change position and a few properties. In Object mode it sets LocRotScale. It also has some handy view settings.

Comment: I have, thanks. That doesn't let me set the value for each of the verts *en-masse*, just the median value.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the positions of single vertices using the properties panel which can be toggled by pressing [N], then under the item tab you can see the XYZ coordinates. You cannot see each verts position individually but you can change them all at once.

Another useful tip is that if you want to  bring a vert to the same plane of another you can select the verts you want to move, and then the one on the X Y or Z you want it to be, and set the transform pivot to active. Then just press [S] to scale the [X], [Y], or [Z] button that correlates and then 0.

(Will add example gifs soon)

Comment: Ok, thanks. So if it doesn't exist I'll stop looking. Seems like it would make a good add-on. Perhaps it's time to get out VSCode and have a crack at it.

Comment: Important to note as stated in the comments of the question that editing multiple vertices locations only edits the mean value. It would be nice to have a way to actually edit all the values at once. You can always set one of the vertices to the desired value, set the pivot point to this vertex and then scale along the desired axis, but it would be nicer to do it in the UI

Comment: @Gorgious  Matter of opinion, in my meta-opinion :) ...One of the things I appreciate about Blender is its attempt at a _minimal_ interface. It's actually quite useful to move offset-bunches of verts around... and for absolute values,  how long does it take, to type SX0, with pivot 'Active', compared to entering numbers in slots? The one shortcut I _do_ miss is the standard 'Create Custom Transform'. It's so basic to the Blenderish workflow, I don't think people should have to make their own.

Comment: @RobinBetts I agree with you, but I think the nuance is not really well explained in the UI and it is not consistent with how it works in most softwares. Moreover it states "Median" when the value shown is the "Mean" value. I would expect to be able to set all the values with pressing ALT before modifying the value like it does with some other fields in blender (another inconsistency in UI) - No UI clutter. To slide a bunch a vertices the shortcut GX* works too